# The timeout specified has expired while trying to commit large files

Tags: svn

We are facing strange issue with our SVN.

- commit works for smaller files, however when my colleague try to commit 3 MB PDF, or a bit larger zip file he sees only Timeout. He is "connecting" via Eclipse to our SVN.

Here are some logs from the time he got timeout.

```
[Mon Dec 08 15:13:32.345525 2014] [dav:error] [pid 29316:tid 1136040256] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.213.64.91:58474] Timeout reading the body (URI: /svn/com.company.dwh/!svn/txr/774-oq/Databases/trunk/doc/HP/samReporting/configuration/company_SAM_SHR_Configuration_and_Operation_Guide_006.pdf)  [408, #0]
[Mon Dec 08 15:14:38.013723 2014] [dav:error] [pid 29316:tid 1324857664] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.213.64.91:58479] Timeout reading the body (URI: /svn/com.company.dwh/!svn/txr/774-or/Databases/trunk/doc/HP/samReporting/configuration/company_SAM_SHR_Configuration_and_Operation_Guide_006.pdf)  [408, #0]
[Mon Dec 08 15:16:53.640390 2014] [dav:error] [pid 29316:tid 1314367808] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.213.64.91:42977] Timeout reading the body (URI: /svn/com.company.dwh/!svn/txr/774-os/Databases/trunk/doc/HP/samReporting/configuration/rtsm/company_Prepare_RTSM_for_SHR.zip)  [408, #0]

svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.4.2 (r22196)
   compiled Aug  5 2009, 19:02:07
```

Anybody can please give me some hints what can go wrong or where to check for some kind of "upload limit"? It can be badly configured Eclipse or something on SVN side or perhaps some Apache limits? But i guess that Apache is out of scope since he is using Eclipse as a client?

If there are more information needed from my side please let me know which one.

Comment: let me know did u test commit 3 MB PDF via client(Tortoise svn) not from Eclipse.it's okay?If not we just only emphasize solution to eclipse plugins.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two directives you may adjust:

- [RequestReadTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html)
- [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

To disable any time/size restriction:

```
    RequestReadTimeout header=0 body=0  # At global level
    LimitRequestBody 0                  # At vhost level
```

Or just don't load the module:

```
# LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
```

Comment: Don't know why everything here is/was downvoted, but that's exactly what was missing for me. Because I've already set the standard timeouts for apache `Timeout` / `KeepAliveTimeout` and those alone didn't help

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it was limitation in Apache config file. Not sure which one, but once you go line by line you can find that.